# mySQL- large database

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, database-recommendation, full-text-search

I need guideline to setup DBMS(MYSQL or SQL Server 2008). The database size is expected upto 80-100GB in next few months. One main table will contain textual content like essays. Can MySQL handle such big size database and can  full text search really work for me for such big database. Should I consider MySQL or any other?

Thanks

Comment: you could consider Solr, which is useful for storing and searching text documents. can be clustered among multiple machines.

Answer (score 2):

> Can MySQL handle such big size database and can full text search really work for me for such 
>   big database

What is big?

SERIOUSLY.

Let's have a look at modern hardware. Databases typcially are large when they are larger than the available RAM.

100gb - hm.

128gb memory was not particularly large last year.

Get a decent modern XEON, put 256GB memory into it.

Just checking - supermicro.com, website has a "featured motherboard". "Supports up to 256 GB DDR3 ECC". Ok, 128gb won't be that expensive.

I have a 64gb database server here that is 5 years old. I have a desktop server that has 64gb memory (micro atx board). Last time I checked, lower mid range servers (two sockets) go to 512gb memory.

That means that by all accounts, 100gb is not large.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of variables that go into database performance. However, MySQL is up to the task you describe given adequate hardware.

I agree with the comment about Solr. It's a great tool.